# Need Help XML from text

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have xml from txt file i got strange error(for me)
There is 2 customers and 6 products on the txt file

as is

Result set is

```
CUSTID  ORDER ID               
98295   29199752211 0   1   2321
98295   29199752211 0   1   76
98295   29199752211 0   2   179
98295   29199752211 0   3   180
98295   29199752211 0   4   320
98295   29199752211 0   5   NULL
```

Why the cust id same ? there is 2 in text file. i'll be glad if i can use some help.

```
        SELECT
            (SELECT LNGNO FROM ARTUT13.DBO.TBLFATURA WHERE TXTOZELKOD=(c6.value('(//FISLER/FIS/FISID)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'))),--[LNGNO] 
            0,--[BYTTUR] 
            c6.value('(KALEMNO)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),--[LNGKALEMSIRA]
            (SELECT LNGKOD FROM ARTUT13.DBO.TBLURUN WHERE TXTKOD=(c6.value('(URUNKODU)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'))),
            c6.value('(MIKTAR)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),--[DBLMIKTAR]
            1,--[BYTBIRIMSIRA]
            1,--[DBLCEVRIM]
            c6.value('(BIRIMFIYAT)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),--[DBLBIRIMFIYAT]
            0,--[BYTKAYITTIP] 
            0,--[BYTDETAYMAL] 
            c6.value('(KDV)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),--[DBLKDVORANI]
            c6.value('(FIYAT)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),--[DBLNETFIYAT]
            '',--[TXTOZELKOD]
            0,--[LNGVADEGUNU]
            GETDATE(),--[TRHSONISLEMTARIHI] 
            'MUHASEBE2',--[TXTSONISLEMHOST]
            '',--[DBLOTV] 
            c6.value('(//FISLER/FIS/FISID)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),--[TXTOZELKOD1] 
            ''--[TXTOZELKOD2]
        from
        (select cast(c1 as xml) from OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\AKTAR\FATURA.txt',SINGLE_BLOB
        ) as T1(c1) )as  T2(c2)
        outer apply c2.nodes('FISLER/FIS/KALEMLER/KALEM')  T6(c6)
```

Text File contains

```
    <FISLER>
       <FIS>
          <FISTIPI>SATIS</FISTIPI>
          <FISID>29199752211</FISID>
          <FISNO>a67502</FISNO>
          <IPTAL>0</IPTAL>
          <TARIH>13.02.2013</TARIH>
          <MUSKODU>35170339P</MUSKODU>
          <MUSADI>MEHMET PEHLIVAN - MORTAN GIDA MEHMET PEHLIVAN</MUSADI>
          <VERGIDAIRESI>KARABURUN MAL MD</VERGIDAIRESI>
          <VERGINO>47035582576</VERGINO>
          <DEPOKODU>01</DEPOKODU>
          <ODEMETIPI>6</ODEMETIPI>
          <TOPLAMBRUT>1200.24</TOPLAMBRUT>
          <TOPLAMISKONTO>60.01</TOPLAMISKONTO>
          <TOPLAMKDV>205.24</TOPLAMKDV>
          <TOPLAMNET>1345.47</TOPLAMNET>
          <SATISTEMSILCISIKODU>001</SATISTEMSILCISIKODU>
          <DAGITICIKODU></DAGITICIKODU>
          <ARACKODU></ARACKODU>
          <ARACPLAKA></ARACPLAKA>
          <SEVKNO></SEVKNO>
          <VADETARIHI>06.03.2013</VADETARIHI>
          <KALEMLER>
             <KALEM>
                <KALEMNO>1</KALEMNO>
                <URUNKODU>4009011024</URUNKODU>
                <URUNADI>EFE KLASİK RAKI45º-100clx12AD TAVA( 63,50 FİYATLI)</URUNADI>
                <MIKTAR>24</MIKTAR>
                <BIRIMFIYAT>50.01</BIRIMFIYAT>
                <FIYAT>1200.24</FIYAT>
                <BIRIM></BIRIM>
                <KDV>18</KDV>
                <ISKONTOLAR>
                   <ISKONTO>
                      <price>1200.24</price>
                      <KODU></KODU>
                      <ADI>Ürün İsk.1</ADI>
                      <TIPI></TIPI>
                      <ORAN>5</ORAN>
                      <TUTAR>60.012</TUTAR>
                   </ISKONTO>
                </ISKONTOLAR>
             </KALEM>
          </KALEMLER>
       </FIS>
       <FIS>
          <FISTIPI>SATIS</FISTIPI>
          <FISID>29199773107</FISID>
          <FISNO>a67511</FISNO>
          <IPTAL>0</IPTAL>
          <TARIH>13.02.2013</TARIH>
          <MUSKODU>100242</MUSKODU>
          <MUSADI>NUMBER ONE APART OTEL RESTAURANT</MUSADI>
          <VERGIDAIRESI>KARABURUN</VERGIDAIRESI>
          <VERGINO>50545253560</VERGINO>
          <DEPOKODU>01</DEPOKODU>
          <ODEMETIPI>6</ODEMETIPI>
          <TOPLAMBRUT>2634.24</TOPLAMBRUT>
          <TOPLAMISKONTO>195.21</TOPLAMISKONTO>
          <TOPLAMKDV>439.03</TOPLAMKDV>
          <TOPLAMNET>2878.06</TOPLAMNET>
          <SATISTEMSILCISIKODU>001</SATISTEMSILCISIKODU>
          <DAGITICIKODU></DAGITICIKODU>
          <ARACKODU></ARACKODU>
          <ARACPLAKA></ARACPLAKA>
          <SEVKNO></SEVKNO>
          <VADETARIHI>06.03.2013</VADETARIHI>
          <KALEMLER>
             <KALEM>
                <KALEMNO>1</KALEMNO>
                <URUNKODU>4001017212</URUNKODU>
                <URUNADI>EFE YAŞ ÜZÜM RAKISI (45º) - 70 cl 12LI KOLİ</URUNADI>
                <MIKTAR>12</MIKTAR>
                <BIRIMFIYAT>47.03</BIRIMFIYAT>
                <FIYAT>564.36</FIYAT>
                <BIRIM></BIRIM>
                <KDV>18</KDV>
                <ISKONTOLAR>
                   <ISKONTO>
                      <price>564.36</price>
                      <KODU></KODU>
                      <ADI>Ürün İsk.1</ADI>
                      <TIPI></TIPI>
                      <ORAN>10</ORAN>
                      <TUTAR>56.436</TUTAR>
                   </ISKONTO>
                </ISKONTOLAR>
             </KALEM>
             <KALEM>
                <KALEMNO>2</KALEMNO>
                <URUNKODU>4001012324</URUNKODU>
                <URUNADI>EFE YAŞ ÜZÜM RAKISI (45º) - 20 cl 24 LU KOLİ</URUNADI>
                <MIKTAR>24</MIKTAR>
                <BIRIMFIYAT>16.07</BIRIMFIYAT>
                <FIYAT>385.68</FIYAT>
                <BIRIM></BIRIM>
                <KDV>18</KDV>
                <ISKONTOLAR>
                   <ISKONTO>
                      <price>385.68</price>
                      <KODU></KODU>
                      <ADI>Ürün İsk.1</ADI>
                      <TIPI></TIPI>
                      <ORAN>10</ORAN>
                      <TUTAR>38.568</TUTAR>
                   </ISKONTO>
                </ISKONTOLAR>
             </KALEM>
             <KALEM>
                <KALEMNO>3</KALEMNO>
                <URUNKODU>4001013724</URUNKODU>
                <URUNADI>EFE YAŞ ÜZÜM RAKISI (45º) - 35 cl 24 LU KOLİ</URUNADI>
                <MIKTAR>24</MIKTAR>
                <BIRIMFIYAT>26.66</BIRIMFIYAT>
                <FIYAT>639.84</FIYAT>
                <BIRIM></BIRIM>
                <KDV>18</KDV>
                <ISKONTOLAR>
                   <ISKONTO>
                      <price>639.84</price>
                      <KODU></KODU>
                      <ADI>Ürün İsk.1</ADI>
                      <TIPI></TIPI>
                      <ORAN>10</ORAN>
                      <TUTAR>63.984</TUTAR>
                   </ISKONTO>
                </ISKONTOLAR>
             </KALEM>
             <KALEM>
                <KALEMNO>4</KALEMNO>
                <URUNKODU>4001011013</URUNKODU>
                <URUNADI>EFE YAŞ ÜZÜM RAKISI (45º) - 100 cl 12LI TAVA</URUNADI>
                <MIKTAR>6</MIKTAR>
                <BIRIMFIYAT>60.37</BIRIMFIYAT>
                <FIYAT>362.22</FIYAT>
                <BIRIM></BIRIM>
                <KDV>18</KDV>
                <ISKONTOLAR>
                   <ISKONTO>
                      <price>362.22</price>
                      <KODU></KODU>
                      <ADI>Ürün İsk.1</ADI>
                      <TIPI></TIPI>
                      <ORAN>10</ORAN>
                      <TUTAR>36.222</TUTAR>
                   </ISKONTO>
                </ISKONTOLAR>
             </KALEM>
             <KALEM>
                <KALEMNO>5</KALEMNO>
                <URUNKODU>4010017001</URUNKODU>
                <URUNADI>EFE 5 YILLIK RAKI45º-70clx3AD KOLİ</URUNADI>
                <MIKTAR>6</MIKTAR>
                <BIRIMFIYAT>113.69</BIRIMFIYAT>
                <FIYAT>682.14</FIYAT>
                <BIRIM></BIRIM>
                <KDV>18</KDV>
             </KALEM>
          </KALEMLER>
       </FIS>
    </FISLER>
```

Comment: Does not look like the result set you have is in any way related to the XML or the query. There is no value `98295` in the XML and there is no `custid` column in the output from the query.

Comment: Yes it does i just coppied the Custid which is <MUSKODU> on txt file. 98295 comes from another table by (SELECT LNGNO FROM ARTUT13.DBO.TBLFATURA WHERE TXTOZELKOD=(c6.value('(//FISLER/FIS/FISID)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'))), thnx

Comment: My guess on this would be that your problem is wherever you use `c6.value('(//FISLER/FIS/FISID)[1]','VARCHAR(100)')` because that will always find the first `FISID` in the XML. Try this instead. `c6.value('(../../FISID)[1]','VARCHAR(100)')`.

Comment: You don't use `MUSKODU` in your query or am I missing something here?

Comment: No my friend i use id of MUSKODU by which i get from query result

Comment: So **which** XML element do you want to retrieve as `CustID` and which other XML element as `Order ID`?? This XML, SQL statement, and output are totally different and don't seem to have to do **anything** with each other..... really hard to even answer anything!

Comment: Just worked fine forme (../../FISID)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') thenk you Mikael Eriksson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your question is not clear: how can be extracted `CUSTID` from that XML ? **There is not `CUSTID` element in that XML.**

2) Very likely, the cause is (if I look at your source code) the usage of absolute references (`.value('(//element...)[1]',...)`) instead of relative references (`.value('(element...)[1]',...)`).

Sample:

```
DECLARE @x XML;
SET @x = N'<...>';
SELECT  c6.value('(//FISLER/FIS/FISID)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS AbsoluteRef_FISID
FROM    @x.nodes('FISLER/FIS/KALEMLER/KALEM')  T6(c6)

SELECT  c6.value('(FISID)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS RelativeRef_FISID
FROM    @x.nodes('FISLER/FIS')  T6(c6)
```

Results:

```
AbsoluteRef_FISID
-------------------
29199752211
29199752211
29199752211
29199752211
29199752211
29199752211

RelativeRef_FISID
-------------------
29199752211
29199773107
```

`//` means absolute references and `c6.value('(//FISLER/FIS/FISID)[1]','VARCHAR(100)')` will extract only the first (`[1]`) `FISID` value from that XML.

`.value('(FISID)[1]',...)` uses a relative reference (relative to `nodes('FISLER/FIS') T6(c6)`) and the result will contains *all* `FISID` values.
If your run this query

```
SELECT  c6.query('.') AS XmlNode
FROM    @x.nodes('FISLER/FIS')  T6(c6);
```

you will get two rows meaning that `.nodes('FISLER/FIS')` will extract two rows

```
XmlNode
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
<FIS><FISTIPI>SATIS</FISTIPI><FISID>29199752211</FISID><FISNO>a67502</FISNO>
<FIS><FISTIPI>SATIS</FISTIPI><FISID>29199773107</FISID><FISNO>a67511</FISNO>
```

from `@x XML` variable. Starting from this point (two rows), the value method `.value('(FISID)[1]',...)` will extract the first `FISID` (`(FISID)[1]`) for every row. Thus, you will get two `FISID` values.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/759c5/7)

Comment: Note: you may use relative ref. thus: `SELECT c6.value('(../../FISID)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS RelativeRef_FISID FROM @x.nodes('FISLER/FIS/KALEMLER/KALEM') T6(c6);`